# Mantine v tippy popovers and the main thread

Tags: popper.js, mantine, tippyjs

On my page, it takes about 10 seconds for all the complex content to load. During that time, my Mantine animated popover doesn't appear until the main thread of execution stops being so busy. But my Tippy animated popover appears right away. How can I adjust the Mantine popover to make it more like the Tippy popover, so it appears right away even when all the content is loading?

There are differences in the layers containing the two animations:

[image: layer containing the non-blocked animation]

[image: layer containing the blocked animation]

I figure I need to somehow enable hardware acceleration for the Mantine popover. Or perhaps it has to do with Mantine's implementation which results in a higher paint count.